# Good dynamics fatal exception from sample app

Tags: android, good-dynamics

Has anyone encountered this error while trying to use Good Dynamics sample applications from their SDK?

It has me stumped as i have included the what should be all the necessary files

```
01-24 06:28:21.463: E/AndroidRuntime(1436): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-24 06:28:21.463: E/AndroidRuntime(1436): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.good.gd.example.policy/com.good.gd.example.policy.ApplicationPolicy}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.good.gd.example.policy.ApplicationPolicy" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.good.gd.example.policy-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.good.gd.example.policy-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
01-24 06:28:21.463: E/AndroidRuntime(1436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
01-24 06:28:21.463: E/AndroidRuntime(1436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
01-24 06:28:21.463: E/AndroidRuntime(1436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-24 06:28:21.463: E/AndroidRuntime(1436):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
01-24 06:28:21.463: E/AndroidRuntime(1436):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-24 06:28:21.463: E/AndroidRuntime(1436):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-24 06:28:21.463: E/AndroidRuntime(1436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-24 06:28:21.463: E/AndroidRuntime(1436):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-24 06:28:21.463: E/AndroidRuntime(1436):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-24 06:28:21.463: E/AndroidRuntime(1436):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-24 06:28:21.463: E/AndroidRuntime(1436):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-24 06:28:21.463: E/AndroidRuntime(1436):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-24 06:28:21.463: E/AndroidRuntime(1436): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.good.gd.example.policy.ApplicationPolicy" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.good.gd.example.policy-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.good.gd.example.policy-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
01-24 06:28:21.463: E/AndroidRuntime(1436):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
01-24 06:28:21.463: E/AndroidRuntime(1436):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
01-24 06:28:21.463: E/AndroidRuntime(1436):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
01-24 06:28:21.463: E/AndroidRuntime(1436):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
01-24 06:28:21.463: E/AndroidRuntime(1436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
01-24 06:28:21.463: E/AndroidRuntime(1436):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Oh it's probably more simply than i think, console output is
GDInternalActivity] Could not find GDInternalActivity.apk!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, first you need to import project from good sdk folder in extras folder of Android SDK folder, then in gd folder...import the project in workspace, then whenevr you try to run any app on Good Technology, create dependency on that imported project. then you dont get exception. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks, i had fixed it since and forgot to update this question since but that was the solution.